# How to delete element in array after socket event in React?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I'm having trouble with React state arrays and hooks. When receiving a socket event

```js
socket.on("connection request", ({address}) => {
    let lastConnection = connections
    lastConnection.push({address, actions: <div className="align-right">
        <MDBBtn color="success" onClick={() => approveConnection(address, false)}>Approve</MDBBtn>
        <MDBBtn color="danger" onClick={() => approveConnection(address, true)}>Refuse</MDBBtn>
    </div>})
    setConnections([...lastConnection])
})
```

I update the list of connections. That part works, but when I try to remove an article from that list using

```js
    const approveConnection = (address, banned) => {
        console.log("removing address " + address + " from " + connections)
        socket.emit("client allow", {address, banned})
        let oldConnections = connections
        oldConnections = oldConnections.filter(a => a.address !== address)
        setConnections([...oldConnections])
    }
```

It works once, but when I try to remove a second one, the first removed pops back into the list and it continues like this when trying to remove another element.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating the state when you add the connection, which might be the reasons for your bug. Instead use functional form of `setState`:

```
socket.on("connection request", ({ address }) => {
  const connection = {
    address,
    actions: {
      address,
      actions: (
        <div className="align-right">
          <MDBBtn
            color="success"
            onClick={() => approveConnection(address, false)}
          >
            Approve
          </MDBBtn>
          <MDBBtn
            color="danger"
            onClick={() => approveConnection(address, true)}
          >
            Refuse
          </MDBBtn>
        </div>
      )
    }
  };
  setConnections(prevConnections => [...prevConnections, connection]);
});
```

Comment: thakns for the fast reply! Though it is more easily readable (I didn't even know you could use this form of setState), it changes nothing regarding my problem, I'm afraid

Comment: Then the issue is most likely in somo other parts of code, maybe the way you're calling `approveConnection`.

Comment: Alright, I managed to fix it; the technique you showed me above for changing the state has been life-saving. Instead of saving the result of the filtered array and then calling setConnections with that argument, I did

setConnections(oldConnections => oldConnections.filter(e => e.address !== address))

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to copy then filter. You can simply filter and pass it to `setConnections`, without `[]`

```
let oldConnections = connections.filter(p => p.address !== address);
setConnections(oldConnections);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! When I change it to what you indicated, oldConnections becomes an empty array

Comment: @MGassend it can be because you have only one element in array and that one has that address, or all your array elements has that address.